# What should i do to keep new widgets always behind old one in kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

When I fire bullets they come on top of old widgets(button,bar,controller,..),what should i do to keep them behind old ones.
Fire button when pressed It add bullets(new widgets) and do animation.
Please guild me to solve this problem.
[image: Overlapping bullets in old widgets(button,..)]

Comment: I would have made 2 layout for the screen: 1 for the front - 1 for the back. They overlap each other and you put stuff on the recquired layer. With this technique, you still need to learn something (and I don't know it). Make your layout "transparent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make 2 Layout for the screen: 1 for the Front - 1 for the Back

The Layout which you declare 1st will be back

The Layout which you declare last will be front

Add bullets(Widgets) on 1st declared Layout.

Add control stuff in front Layout